# Where does the excess 20px come from?

Tags: html, css, localized

I'm developing a website from the ground up and there seems to be an extra twenty (or so) pixels that are displaying at the very bottom of the webpage. Instead of ending at the last element, the page continues and shows the `body` background. I've tried using Firebug and have fiddled with about every element in the css file, but can't find what is causing the excess pixels to show.

Any help on figuring this out is very much appreciated.

**Screenshot of Problem:**

[image: help!]

Comment: Did you solve it? I can't see it in FF 18.

Comment: No, not yet. Odd.. I'm still seeing it in FF 18.0.2 on Mac, though

Comment: Are you referring the extra 20px below the images? If so, the `<div class="main-wrap row"></div>` is causing the extra 20 because of it's `margin-bottom: 20px` from the css file.

Comment: @justin.chmura THANK YOU!! Can't believe I missed that. Now fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its coming from here:

```
.main-wrap {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to @Eric Lemos and others who figured this out. I'm building off of a framework which has its own CSS file for certain elements. I should have checked there first. Thanks again all.

Comment: no problem, Bert Macklin.

Answer (score 1):

it comes from main-wrap class style:

```
.main-wrap {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

remove it and you're fine :)

By the way, it's referenced here:

```
<div class="main-wrap row">




        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/goqhe4ff.js"></script>
            </div>
```